# How much sugar and potassium nitrate I would need to make a rocket reach the moon?

Tags: science-based, physics, astrophysics

I know the question itself is kinda crazy, but a rocket need a fuel and a oxidiser to work. And in this case, the oxidiser is **potassium nitrate**.

Well, in this video, this guy makes a homemade rocket using these two ingredients (and other things):

"How To Make Sugar Rockets":
https://youtu.be/12fR9neVnS8

Anyway, I know if it was this simple to make a sugar rocket, NASA would have done it a long time ago. So, comparing to other rockets how much it would cost to launch a sugar rocket that could reach the moon?

Comment: This reads like a physics homework question rather than a question about building a fictional world.

Comment: Do you want to be able to come back again, or are you happy to stay on the moon once you’ve reached it?

Comment: IIRC, Mythbusters did an episode on sugar-fueled rockets that may be relevant...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. You just need to impact the moon, not land or orbit.
2. Your last spacehip's final payload is 1 kg.
3. You can build rockets with a mass fraction of 10:1 (10 parts fuel for 1 part structure)
4. There is zero mass required for avionics, staging, etc.
5. Thrust-to mass ratio is ignored. Air resistance is ignored. Gravity losses are ignored. We pretend all stages fire, and stage, and fire and stage and... at ground level.

Sugar rocket ISP is about 120, for the very best you can make.

Assuming you manage to build your rocket with a fuel to inert mass ratio of 10:1 (this is ludicrously optimistic, sugar rockets are not known for space-age material and engineering science!), then you can get a delta-v of about 2.1km/s
You need a total delta-v of about 12km/s to get a Moon flyby. (actually about 1.5km/s more due to the cheating in point (5) above)

(stage numbering in reverse order from the usual, because its easier to keep track)

rocket:
payload = 1kg (the payload only)
Rocket body = 1kg
Fuel = 10kg
This stage Deltav = 2.1km/s

NO problem, just build it as a multistage rocket!
With the parameters chosen (mass ratio 10:1, payload mass = rocket body mass), this works out to a convenient factor 14 scaling each stage.

Second stage:
payload = 12kg (the final stage)
Rocket body = 12kg
Fuel = 120kg
This stage Deltav = 2.1km/s, total so far 4.2km/s

Third stage:
payload = 144kg (the final 2 stages)
Rocket body = 144kg
Fuel = 1440kg
This stage Deltav = 2.1km/s, total so far 6.3km/s

Fourth stage:
payload = 1728kg (the final 3 stages)
Rocket body = 1728kg
Fuel = 17280kg
This stage Deltav = 2.1km/s, total so far 8.4km/s

Fifth stage:
payload = 20736kg (the final 4 stages)
Rocket body = 20736kg
Fuel = 207360kg
This stage Deltav = 2.1km/s, total so far 10.5km/s

Sixth stage:
payload = 248822kg (the final 5 stages)
Rocket body = 248822kg
Fuel = 2488220kg
This stage Deltav = 2.1km/s, total so far 12.6km/s

**Congratulations, you have made it, with some cheating**
Total mass of the rocket at launch = 3257173 kg

---

**But what if you want to not just impact the Moon, but land and return?**

For doing this without cheating the gravity losses and air drag, add 1 more stage. i.e. multiply the mass by 14

To do a landing on the moon, add (a bit more than) another stage. multiply the mass by 14.
To do a land and return, add another 3 stages. We assume aerobraking in atmosphere, of course. So multiply the mass by another 14 *14 *14

Final mass for moon land and return, direct ascent profile...
About 24525001361728 kg
(245 billion tonnes)
.
.
.
For a 1kg payload.

Comment: thats quite a large amount

Comment: I wouldn't have believed that you could get enough delta-V out of sugar (carbon's awfully light) to get out of the atmosphere, so neat calculations!

Comment: There was nothing left for me to do here but upvote.  That and say ... "but what if you use *radioactive* potassium?" :)

Comment: @jdunlop if the rocket is capable of lifting itself and *any* payload, *any* distance... then it can go to the moon. You should see the same calculation for a water-bottle rocket!! The launch mass is heavier than Jupiter! (and about 4500 stages, if i remember correctly)

Comment: You can kinda wing it with gravity/aerodynamic drag losses by adding an extra ~2km/s to your delta-V budget. Slap an extra stage on there and call it a day.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Yarp. That's what I did in the first line below the "...but land and return" subsection. Besides, the whole thing is pretty much "winging it", its just to illustrate what a Tyrant the rocket equations can be

Comment: @PcMan ahh yes. I was ignoring that lower section; landing with a solid rocket was a silly step too far.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Yarp again. I've done it in KSP. and YES, it is a very silly thing indeed.